# How to get the list request from android to asp.net webservice?

Tags: asp.net

i have one webservice,use one webmethod,In android developer pass the request in List 
Example:

```
Itemid Itemname Date
1      aaaa     12/4/2013
2      bbbb     11/4/2013
3      cccc     10/4/2013
```

How to get this request in webservice?..and how to receive this request? Advance thanks....

Comment: need to give reference of your webservice in website...